# UISwitch control not working properly in Xcode 5

Tags: uidatepicker, uiswitch, ios7, xcode5

Recently i updated my Xcode 4.6.3 to Xcode5 DP2.Everything was working fine in Xcode 4.6.3.I mean inside a Viewcontroller there is a UISwitch and UIDatePicker and two buttons "set" and "clear". When I select a particular time from UIDatePicker and change the UISwitch state to "on" and by clicking the "set" button an alarm is set for the selected time. And if I change the UISwitch state to "off" UIDatePicker will show the current time otherwise the selected time.This was working fine in Xcode 4.6.3. But after updating to Xcode5 DP2,everytime i toggle the  UISwitch state,UIDatePicker is returning back to the current time,I mean even if i select a time other than the current time in UIDatePicker and toggle UISwitch to "on" state UIDatePicker returns back to current time.I dont know what is going on here.Is there any problem with   Xcode5 DP2..Please help me..

This is my code:

```
-(IBAction) switchValueChanged
{
NSString *value = @"OFF";

if (switch1.on)
{
    value = @"ON";
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:value forKey:@"stateOfSwitch"];           

    [switch1 setOn:YES animated:YES];
      }
else
{
 [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:value forKey:@"stateOfSwitch"];
           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
       }
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I spend too much time trying to make it work, but apparently it's an issue with the xcode 5 simulator.

Just run it on a device and you should see that the nsuserdefaults will be working fine.

Hope this serves.